# Spring batch job is thread-safe?

Tags: spring-batch

I need to parallelize a single step of a batch spring job. Before the step to be parallelized, tasklets are run that put some results in the parameters of the job.
The results produced by the tasklets, are necessary to execute the Partitioner and the Items of the step to be parallelized.
A doubt is arising that I really can't solve. Since I can have the same job running simultaneously multiple times with different initial parameters, are the tasklets and step items safe thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, tasklets and chunk-oriented step components are not thread-safe. If they are shared between multiple job instances/executions running concurrently, you need to make them thread-safe.

You can achieve this by using `JobScope`d steps and `StepScope`d readers/writers. You can also use the `SynchronizedItemStreamReader` and the ([upcoming](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2762)) `SynchronizedItemStreamWriter` to make readers and writers thread-safe. All item readers and writers provided by Spring Batch have a mention about their thread-safety in the Javadoc.

Comment: I created all the tasklets for the steps with the annotation Component and StepScope.  I created all the readers, written and step processors with annotations Component and StepScope. I created a Partitioner with annotations Component and StepScope.
- I created a JobExecutionDecider and a JobExecutionListenerSupport with annotations Component and JobScope.

I tried with the simultaneous execution of two instances of the same job with different parameters and I verified that in this way the two jobs are totally independent.
Is my result right?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Each thread will have its own instance of each component.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to run multiple instances of the same job.   It would be better to run multiple tasks or processes in the same step and or job.   You might want to lookup job partitioning, and or Remote Chucking to do concurrent processing.

If it has to be isolated jobs then you might have your concurrent jobs write out to say a message que as their end (writer) step, and then have another job listen to read from that que.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/cases/parallel.html